# How to combine AWS SES and Namecheap Private Pro Email

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, dns, amazon-ses, namecheap

I'm using Ruby On Rails 7, hosted on Heroku. I send mails via AWS SES. I put AWS SES MX record and DNS record on my Namecheap domain. So my identity has been proved.

My problem is that I just bought **Private Email** on Namecheap too, to have pro emails *(ex: "myname@mydomaine.com")*.

The **Private Email** I just bought replaces the MX record of Amazon SES so I can't use both at the same time. I can't choose on my Namecheap interface MX record **+** Private Email.

What should I do? I'm ready to move from Namecheap if needed to.
How companies send mail AND have custom mail domain?

I searched for similar issues on Internet but didn't find.

I contacted Namecheap and they told me that yes, we cannot have MX records **+** Private Email at the same time.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: No sorry mate. I migrated to PostmarkApp who works with my domain and namecheap. Sorry